# How to use bootstrap.static with flask-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask

When I use Flask-Bootstrap, it will use css/js resources from CDN. If I access the url(http://127.0.0.1) without internet, the css or js will be lost.

How to use local resources of flask-bootstrap? such as:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/static/css
lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/static/js
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here a minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True #This turns file serving static

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('main.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [Flask-Bootstrap documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/configuration.html):

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL
```

> If True, Bootstrap resources will be served from the local app instance every time. See CDN-delivery in Flask-Bootstrap for details.

Set this to true in your app's config and the files will be served locally instead of from a CDN.